# Transpose some columns to rows using pivot with SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, sql-server-2012, transpose

MS SQL Server 2012

I have a table called **indexrows**

```
name    displayname propertyvalue
abc      $row1        agg
abc      $row2        spx
abc      $row3        qqq
def      $row1        spx
def      $row2        qqq
```

I would like to transpose these results to look like this.

```
name    $row1   $row2   $row3
abc      agg    spx    qqq
def      spx    qqq
```

I tried the following query without success. I get this error

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'.

```
select * 
from (
select 
name,propertyvalue, displayname
from indexrows
) a
PIVOT 
(
propertyvalue
for [displayname] in ('$row1', '$row2', '$row3')
) as pivot
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things are wrong with your query.

First, you are missing an aggregate function on your PIVOT. You need an aggregate around `propertyvalue`.

Second, you need to surround the `$row1`, etc with square brackets not single quotes.

Third, I would use a different alias for the `as pivot`

As a result the code will be:

```
select * 
from 
(
  select name, propertyvalue, displayname
  from indexrows
) a
pivot
(
  max(propertyvalue)
  for [displayname] in ([$row1], [$row2], [$row3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48e3e/10)

Answer (score 3):

PIVOTs need an aggregate function, because you could have multiple entries in the original table.  If you know you only have one value per key, then just use MIN().

Also, '$row1', '$row2', '$row3' are now columns and need to be delimited like columns

```
select * 
from (
  select 
  name,propertyvalue, displayname
  from indexrows
) a
PIVOT 
(
MIN(propertyvalue)
for [displayname] in ([$row1], [$row2], [$row3])
) as pivot
```

Comment: anon I get the following error with your query  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'pivot'.

Comment: I overlooked the third error in your original example: using the keyword 'pivot' as an alias.  This may not always throw an error, but it's always a bad idea.