# Dynamic column to rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

I have following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PC_Adjustments](
    [Property_Adjustment_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [property_id] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Adjustment_amount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Adjustment_Desc] [nvarchar](2000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into PC_Adjustments values(12,2.3,'test1')
insert into PC_Adjustments values(12,4.3,'test2')
insert into PC_Adjustments values(12,4.3,'test3')
insert into PC_Adjustments values(12,6.3,'test4')
insert into PC_Adjustments values(13,2.3,'test31')
insert into PC_Adjustments values(13,2.3,'testd1')
insert into PC_Adjustments values(13,2.3,'test41')
insert into PC_Adjustments values(14,2.3,'test561')
```

In the above scenario for property_id 12 having 4 rows,13 having 3 its may be increase or decrese.what i meant to say is its dynamic rows.

i need following output.

```
property_id Adjustment_1    Amount  Adjustment_2    Amount  Adjustment_3    Amount  Adjustment_4    Amount
12           test1          2.3  test2           4.3      test3           4.3     test4          6.3
13          test31          2.3  testd1          2.3      test41          2.3     NULL            NULL
14          test561         2.3   NULL           NULL      NULL         NULL      NULL          NULL
```

I am using MSSQL 2008.

Comment: Look at Pivot table - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: when you typed the title, didn't you see similar posts? I'm sure there are million duplicates..

Comment: is there any posible with out using pivot

Comment: @Sree - I think It can be easily done with Pivot and am not aware of any other way - you can looks at an example here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458894/transpose-some-columns-to-rows-using-pivot-with-sql

Comment: All post using static columns..:(,i need two dynamic columns

Comment: I need to multiple rows as columns

Answer (score 1):

The trick to doing dynamic pivoting is getting the column names.  This can be done using the "STUFF" function.

I ran into this exact problem not a week or two ago.  My case was a little more difficult as I was attempting to double-pivot, but this answer provided a great walkthrough, step-by-step as to how it works.  You should be able to get the gist of what you need to do and avoid dealing with the extra pivot.

[SQL Double Dynamic Pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962018/sql-double-dynamic-pivot)

This should walk you through what you're trying to do.

Comment: My question and provided answer are diffrent